# Scala SBT Inline Dependency Declaration

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, ivy

Scala SBT manual apparently says that there is some "lightweight alternative to Ivy" called "inline declarations"

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html

I have a single jar file ( printer_2.11-1.0.jar ) with no dependencies or imports what so ever that I created with "sbt package". I want to get this jar to a place on the internet where I can include it into my future projects as soon as possible. I don't know how to use Ivy or Maven. Can someone give me a solution that can get my jar listed as fast as possible?

Solved:

```
libraryDependencies += "printer" % "printer" % "2.11" from "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/214507961/printer_2.11-1.0.jar"
```

^ The jar file is posted to a public dropbox folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658213/simple-way-to-add-jar-url-as-dependency-in-sbt

Answer (score 0):

You are misreading the manual. Going to section [Inline Declarations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Inline+Declarations). The text reads:

> Inline declarations are a basic way of specifying the dependencies to be automatically retrieved. They are intended as a lightweight alternative to a full configuration using Ivy.

This is an example inline definition of a dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision
```

which will be normally resolved through Ivy. The sentence does not say 'lightweight alternative to Ivy', it means:

> They are intended as an Ivy based automatically resolved lightweight alternative to specifying a full configuration manually.

The latter being:

> Manually managing dependencies involves copying any jars that you want to use to the lib directory.

Comment: Please just tell me. If I have a jar named "printer_2.11-1.0.jar" in Google drive at "foo.drive.printer_2.11-1.0.jar", what line do I have to copy-paste into my sbt file?

Comment: libraryDependencies += "printer" % "printer" % "foo.drive.printer_2.11-1.0.jar"

Comment: @MichaelLafayette you can add `from <url>`, see [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Explicit+URL).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution...

```
libraryDependencies += "printer" % "printer" % "2.11" from "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/214507961/printer_2.11-1.0.jar"
```

^ The jar file is posted to a public dropbox folder. This jar file makes print statements easier to locate.